# make a vertical separator line in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I am a beginner in HTML/CSS and I have gone through many StackOverflow links but none worked. So I need to implement a vertical line as shown in the below picture. Thanks in advance

```css
.root_class {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 75%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: thin solid #ccc;
}

.text {
  font-size: 3rem;
  margin: 0;
  margin-right: 10rem;
}

.percentile-card {
  transition: 0.3s;
  margin: 1rem;
  padding: 5px;
}

.percentile-card p {
  margin: 0;
}

.percentile-card p:first-child {
  color: #bbb;
}
```

```html
<div class="root_class rhs-background">
        <p class="text">Where Do i Stand Overall ?</p>
        <hr width="1" size="500">
        <div class="percentile-card text-center">
          <h4>You did better Than</h4>
          <i class="fa fa-users pull-left" style="margin-left: 40px;" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <h5><b>60%</b></h5>
        </div>
      </div>
```

[image]

Comment: I can see vertical line, you want that line to touch both upper and lower div border ? you can also use `border-left` for `h4` element

Comment: I have added an image and border-left doesn't touch the upper and lower div border. Check the question for image

Answer (score 0):

You ca add Margin:0 to the line:

```css
.root_class {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 75%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: thin solid #ccc;
}

.text {
  font-size: 3rem;
  margin: 0;
  margin-right: 10rem;
}

.percentile-card {
  transition: 0.3s;
  margin: 1rem;
  padding: 5px;
}

.percentile-card p {
  margin: 0;
}

.VerticalLine {
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  width: 15px;
  background: teal;
}

.percentile-card p:first-child {
  color: #bbb;
}
```

```html
<div class="root_class rhs-background">
  <p class="text">Where Do i Stand Overall ?</p>
  <hr class="VerticalLine" width="5px" size="500">
  <div class="percentile-card text-center">
    <h4>You did better Than</h4>
    <i class="fa fa-users pull-left" style="margin-left: 40px;" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <h5><b>60%</b></h5>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I mean you can see it in the snippet! may be something with the actual code? you have to add a class in HTML. Check the html code as well.'

Comment: it is not there I even inspected and changed few properties but doesn't working

Comment: You should share more info because I have no idea what's happening, from the snippet you have I was able to fix. Is it possible to share full actual code in the form of snippet to take closer look?

Comment: Hmmmm strange, I just want to check you added this?  `<hr class="VerticalLine" width="5px" size="500">` because I have used selector for the `<hr`>.

Comment: yes I checked again that  code is there and I also updated the question check it out

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212133/discussion-between-manjuboyz-and-prem).

Answer (score 0):

[Code from W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_vertical_line2)

```html
<style>
.vl {
  border-left: 6px solid green;
  height: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -3px;
  top: 0;
}
</style>


<h2>Vertical Line</h2>

<div class="vl"></div>
```

Code from me;

```css
.root_class {
  display: flex;
  height : 100px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 75%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: thin solid #ccc;
}

.text {
  font-size: 22px;
  margin-right : 25px;
}

.percentile-card {
  transition: 0.3s;
  margin: 1rem;
  padding: 5px;
}
.vl {
  border-left: 6px solid green;
  height: 100px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -3px;
  top: 0;
}

.percentile-card p:first-child {
  color: #bbb;
}
.rate{

margin-left : 60px;

}
.better{
    margin-top : 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="root_class">

        <p class="text">Where Do i Stand Overall ?</p>
          <div class="vl"></div>
          <div class="percentile-card text-center">

              <h4 class="better">You did better Than</h4>
                <h5 class="rate"><b>60%</b></h5>
          </div>
    
</div>
```

Comment: it's not working like check ourself before posting it as answer

Comment: its not working in my case it is acting as sticky position

Comment: If you click Run code snippet you can see. Maybe you didn't get the css.

Answer (score 0):

> **You can do it simply two ways:**
>
> 1. add margin 0 in hr, like in css add hr { margin: 0; }
> 2. Or, you can try after content positioning as below code (more
>      flexible)

```css
.root_class {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: stretch;
  width: 75%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: thin solid #ccc;
  height: 400px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #fff 75%, #00a);
}

.text {
  font-size: 3rem;
  margin: 0;
  padding-right: 5rem;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}
.text:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 1px;
  background-color: black;
}

hr{
  margin: 0;
}

.percentile-card {
  transition: 0.3s;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 1rem;
}

.percentile-card p {
  margin: 0;
}

.percentile-card p:first-child {
  color: #bbb;
}
```

```html
<div class="root_class rhs-background">
  <p class="text">Where Do i Stand Overall ?</p>
  <div class="percentile-card text-center">
    <h4>You did better Than</h4>
    <i class="fa fa-users pull-left" style="margin-left: 40px;" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <h5><b>60%</b></h5>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<hr style="width:100px; transform:rotate(90deg);">
```

Try it